# Accessing multi-dimensional, unordered, associative arrays in an ordered fashion using an incremental loop

Tags: php, arrays, csv, dictionary

This is primarily a PHP answer, but the methodology may in fact be language agnostic.

After running a CSV file through a simple parser, I was given a multidimensional array that resembled something akin to this:

```
array( 'estimated' =>
  array( 
    array( "TITLE" => 'MAIN', "CURR_PERF" => 100, "POT_PERF" => 75 ),
    array( "TITLE" => 'HEAT', "CURR_PERF" => 90, "POT_PERF" => 60 ),
    array( "TITLE" => 'CO2', "CURR_PERF" => 56, "POT_PERF" => 40 ),
  ),

 'actual' => 
   array(
    array( "TITLE" => 'MAIN', "CURR_PERF" => 100, "POT_PERF" => 75 ),
    array( "TITLE" => 'HEAT', "CURR_PERF" => 89 , "POT_PERF" => 75),
    array( "TITLE" => 'CO2', "CURR_PERF" => 40, "POT_PERF" => 20 ),
   );
);
```

Now, horrific data structure to one side, without refactoring of the underlying parser - how would be the best way to ensure that you can access these in a specific order? **Without necessarily touching the underlying parser?**

If you loop through using a `for()`/`foreach()` loop you're only going to be able to read them in a linear order - increasing or decreasing down the elements. You're not necessarily going to be able to drill down and get the specific value required.

For instance, the CSV file could express the values for `estimated` in a different order to the values for `actual`; and it may be required that they are output in yet another order.

For example, here are three different orders off the top of my head:

```
-> MAIN HEAT CO2
-> HEAT MAIN CO2
-> CO2  HEAT MAIN
```

Furthermore, as is quite usual, the label names in the CSV file are not exactly user-friendly - so they need to be '*translated*' (if you like) in to something more human-friendly. Naturally, without the use of lots of `if()` statements if preferable!

Given it's a very specific use case, but it's something I've seen before with regards to arrays being serialised - and often finding out that they are actually nested.

I've posted one possible solution, but would be happy to see others. (In the past when I've done similar I've never accepted my own answer ;)) I'm sure there must be a more elegant way than the one I've devised..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the quickest (and neatest) solution I could come up with on the spot at the time, but it's not one that I take very much pride in..! It involves multiple loops, the use of several arrays and seems to be an over-engineered mechanism for doing something which should surely be pretty simplistic?

First of all I've created an associative array to use as a dictionary to look up translations for text strings found in the CSV file:

```
$tbl = array( "MAIN"=>"Main Costs",
  "TOTAL"=>"Total Costs",
  "CO2"=>"Gas expended" );
```

Next up, I created an array to use as an 'index' - I entered the `key` values here in the order I would like them to be accessed in the application:

```
$index = array( "MAIN", "TOTAL", "CO2" );
```

I then created two blank arrays and populated them with the data from the child arrays, by using a loop I was able to make them associative - allowing me to specify use the `TITLE` fields as keys:

```
$estimated = array();
$actual = array();

foreach( $bills['estimated'] as $bill ){
  $estimated[ $bill['title'] ] = $bill;
}
foreach( $bills['actual'] as $bill ){
  $actual[ $bill['title'] ] = $bill;
}
```

By doing this I could loop through them in a specific order, regardless of the order they were parsed in, like so:

```
 for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
   $bill = $estimated[ $index[ $i ] ];
   printf(" %s: %d ", $tbl[ $index[ $i ] ], $bill['CURR_PERF'] );
}
```

Which would output the following, in the order I specified:

```
// 1. Main Costs: 100
// 2. Total Costs: 90
// 3. Gas Expended: 56
```

Naturally, this order could easily be changed if required. It does however:

- require using an array specifically to act as an index
- require using two loops simply to initialise
- uses a total of four extra arrays

Answer (score 0):

If this array was assigned to variable `$ary` like:

```
$ary = array(
  'estimated' =>
    array( 
      array('TITLE' => 'MAIN', 'CURR_PERF' => 100, 'POT_PERF' => 75),
      array('TITLE' => 'HEAT', 'CURR_PERF' => 90, 'POT_PERF' => 60),
      array('TITLE' => 'CO2', 'CURR_PERF' => 56, 'POT_PERF' => 40),
    ),
  'actual' => 
     array(
       array('TITLE' => 'MAIN', 'CURR_PERF' => 100, 'POT_PERF' => 75),
       array( 'TITLE' => 'HEAT', 'CURR_PERF' => 89 , 'POT_PERF' => 75),
       array( 'TITLE' => 'CO2', 'CURR_PERF' => 40, 'POT_PERF' => 20 ),
     );
);
```

Your `estimated` array could be accessed like:

```
$newVar = $ary['estimated'][2]['CURR_PERF'];
```

`$newVar` would be `56`. You can reassign a value as well, like:

```
$ary['estimated'][0]['POT_PERF'] = 300;
```

That first array in the `estimated` array used to be `75` and is now `300`.

This is how you get and set specific values in a Multi-dimensional Array.

To sort the arrays, if you need to loop over and maintain their indexes, see PHP's `uasort()` function. This may take some work, on your part, to develop a `cmp_function`, but should do what you're looking for in a different way.

See,

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

and

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php ,

which explains `cmp_function` better.

Comment: I fear you've misunderstood the question somewhat, I understand how to access the data. (That should be quite evident from the question itself!) This primarily regards things such as accessing nested associative arrays without knowing the order, and preferably without any further data structures or excess flow control structures.

Comment: Maybe you should look into `uasort()` at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php and `usort()` at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php, because it explains `cmp_function`.